# forge-rim configurator-inventor error issue occured

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

public async Task OnCallback(string id/*, [FromBody]dynamic body*/, DateTime? ifModifiedSince)
{
try
{
dynamic oauth = await OAuthController.GetInternalAsync();
string bucketkey = "inventorilogicda" + nickName.ToLower();

```
            ObjectsApi objectsApi = new ObjectsApi();
            objectsApi.Configuration.AccessToken = oauth.access_token;

            dynamic objIPT = await objectsApi.GetObjectDetailsAsync(bucketkey,  outputIPTFile);
            dynamic objIDW = await objectsApi.GetObjectDetailsAsync(bucketkey, outputIDWFile);
            
            dynamic urnIPT = TranslateObject(objIPT, outputIPTFile);
            dynamic urnIDW = TranslateObject(objIDW, outputIDWFile);

           await _hubContext.Clients.Client(id).SendAsync("onTranslate", (string)await urnIPT, (string) await urnIDW);
         
            dynamic signedIPTUrl = objectsApi.CreateSignedResourceAsyncWithHttpInfo(bucketkey, outputIPTFile, new PostBucketsSigned(10), "read");
            dynamic signedIDWUrl = objectsApi.CreateSignedResourceAsyncWithHttpInfo(bucketkey, outputIDWFile, new PostBucketsSigned(10), "read");
            dynamic signedPDFUrl = objectsApi.CreateSignedResourceAsyncWithHttpInfo(bucketkey, outputPDFile, new PostBucketsSigned(10), "read");

            await _hubContext.Clients.Client(id).SendAsync("downloadResult", (string)(await signedIPTUrl).Data.signedUrl, (string)(await signedIDWUrl).Data.signedUrl, (string)(await signedPDFUrl).Data.signedUrl);
            return Ok();

        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
        return Ok();
    }
```

Getting error while calling the below method.
await CreateWorkItem(value);

dynamic objIPT = await objectsApi.GetObjectDetailsAsync(bucketkey,  outputIPTFile);
in the above line i am getting error lik below.

Autodesk.Forge.Client.ApiException: 'Error calling GetObjectDetails: {"reason":"Object not found"}'